# Quasi-concavity and contour sets

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Hi I'm trying to prove a function f is quasiconcave if the upper contour set of f with cutoff a is convex. Could someone please give me some idea on how to start or think about the direction of this proof. I can do the reverse way (f quasi concave implies upper contour is convex).

Comment: anyone any suggestions ! Highly appreciated !

Comment: hi everyone any suggestions: should I be thinking of setting the cutoff equal to the infimum of the family of functions produced from x in C+.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is nothing to prove. What OP writes is the definition.

Answer (score 0):

The other direction:

A function ${\displaystyle f:S\to \mathbb {R} } $ defined on a convex subset S of a real vector space is quasiconcave if for all ${\displaystyle x,y\in S} $ and ${\displaystyle \lambda \in [0,1]}$ we have
${\displaystyle f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda )y)\geq \min {\big \{}f(x),f(y){\big \}}.} $

Let us take any two points $x,y$. Clearly, $x,y\in\{z:f(z)\geq \min {\big \{}f(x),f(y){\big \}}\}.$ We are given that this set is convex.

Hence,

${\displaystyle f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda )y)\geq \min {\big \{}f(x),f(y){\big \}}.} $

Comment: This is definition of quasi-concave function NOT Quasi convex function.

Comment: I know, it was a typo. Quasi concavity is what is being asked for, if you see the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use method of contradiction.
Suppose $f$ is not quasi-concavity, i.e., $f(x^\alpha)< \min \{f(x'),f(x'')\}$. The upper contour set $U_\alpha$ for $ \alpha = \min \{f(x'), f(x'')\}$ contains $x'$, $x''$, but not $x^\alpha$. Contradict to $U_\alpha$ is convex.